# How to load image from external storage after saved with Media store Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I saved some images on the 'Pictures/MY_PATH_FOLDER' folder and saved the name file on my db.
I use this code:

```
OutputStream fos;
try {
    BitmapDrawable imgDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) ivImage.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = imgDrawable.getBitmap();

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,nameFile);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpeg");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + 
                      File.separator + MY_PATH_FOLDER);
                
    Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,contentValues);
    fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fos);
    Objects.requireNonNull(fos);

    Log.d(TAG,"IMAGE SAVED!");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"ERROR: \n" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

But now I trying to get the images and display them in an `ImageView` but I don't find a way to do it. Please, help.

Comment: Use `imageUri`, the value that is returned from `insert()` on `ContentResolver`.